# Confusion in using SSL virtualMIN and wordpress website

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, hosting, webmin, virtualmin

I have a domain (e.g.) example.com

I am using a virtual machine in a cloud having public IP. on this VM i am also using VirtualMin for shared hosting. so i have multple URLS to access different services such as email,wordpress, virtualmin console, and website address. now i need to use SSL on all these addresses however all these address does not change the sub domain. so do i need to buy wildcard (which is very expensive) or i can use simple SSL.

here are the site links that i need to encrypt.

Website https://example.com (hosted via virtualmin)

Email  https://example.com/mail (hosted via virtualmin)

Wordpress  https://example.com/wp-admin (hosted via virtualmin)

virtualmin  https://example.com:10000 (virtualmin console)

virtualmin email  https://example.com:20000 (virtualmin email console)

as you can see all these URLS has no change in sub domains rather port and landing directories are change. so do i need Normal SSL for all these links or i need wildcard ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A Normal SSL will be fine for your needs, I would suggest creating a self signed certificate to test out your setup. Another tip is to look into the Let's Encrypt option as that will allow you to set up a Let's Encrypt certificate.

```
Virtualmin > Server Configuration > Manage SSL Certificate > Let's Encrypt
```

And then you will need to follow this guide:

https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/tutorial/how-to-add-an-ssl-certificate

Once you have the SSL installed you then need to apply it to all the parts of the server via

```
Virtualmin > Server Configuration > Manage SSL Certificate > Current Certificate > Copy to Webmin / Copy to Usermin / Copy to Dovecot / Copy to Postfix
```